# Transform string to the_geom in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I created the following table in postgreSQL:

```
create table idLatLongTable
(id character varying(250), latLong character varying(250), the_geom geometry);
```

containing the following values for columns (id, latLong):

```
id_1     POLYGON (1.137821,-129.141488|1.137874,-129.141493|1.137970,-129.141403|1.137994,-129.141349|1.138021,-129.141238)
id_2     LINESTRING (7.294799,-122.935414|7.294679,-122.935129)
id_3     POLYGON (1.139228,-129.143349|1.139228,-129.143401|1.139150,-129.143461|1.138930,-129.143451|1.138734,-129.143445|1.138630,-129.143390|1.138007,-129.142777|1.137906,-129.142629|1.137761,-129.142286|1.137796,-129.142214|1.137844,-129.142142|1.137839,-129.142067)
id_4     POINT (1.138007,-129.142777)
```

However, I am not able to understand as to:-- how to traverse the string in latLong column such that I can run an update command for the three geometry types: POINT, LINESTRING and POLYGON.

I know had lat, long been separately mentioned, then I can run the update command for inserting values into "geometry" column as:

```
UPDATE idLatLongTable SET the_geom = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' ||
longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')',4326);
```

My question is: How can I convert the strings in "latLong" column into the_geom data type (geometry column)

Comment: Where those values in `latLong` are coming from? Because, it seems to me that they are in [**almost** the right format](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html). Just replace commas with spaces, `|` with commas, and some more parenthesis are required in some types.

Comment: @pozs These values are coming from some company owned dataset

Comment: Nah, I mean technically. Are they in some standard? What do you know about their format exactly? Are they completely a black box? If that is the case, please try to collect as much sample as it's reasonable (at least one sample of every "subtype" -- like `POLYGON`, `LINESTRING`, etc. -- you need to deal with).

Comment: Do you need to transform data that is already in the DB or are you talking of doing this only for future data. While postgresql rocks at geospatial it isn't so hot at string manipulation